# Odoo 8 - How to avoid the 'save' state of a form view after refreshing this form view with a button?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10, odoo-view

I Have a form view which contains several fields (char, date, selection...).

The problem is when I fill the fields of the form view and if I click on my action button during the filling of the fields of my view form, it refreshes me the form view (which is good), but the problem is once the refreshing done, the view form is in 'save' mode with my previous filled fields like that :

[image: save mode]

I don't want this type of behavior. I just want the default appearance of the form view, once the refreshing done.

Actually, I have to manually click on `other options` button and then click on `delete` button to have the default form view.

Here is the configuration of my action button :

**Python side**

```python
@api.multi
def refreshPage(self):
    return ({
        'type': 'ir.actions.client',
        'tag': 'reload'})
```

**X.M.L side**

```xml
<button string="Rejet&#x00E9;e"
        type='object'
        name='refreshPage'
        confirm="&#x00CA;tes-vous s&#x00FB;r de vouloir rejeter la demande?"                                                                                                         
        attrs="{'invisible':
               [('dropDownList1', '=', False),
               ('dropDownList2', '=', False),
               ('dropDownList3', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean, it should be in edit mode after refresh not in save mode?

Comment: I also have an edit button, to resume the previous state after refreshing the form view. The form view is probably in edit mode as you said. If it is, I will change my title and the rest of my question.